# NHibernate using optional where

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, linq-to-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Is there a way in Nhibernate to query with an optional where clause.

I have a query below with a list of Ids passed in:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Orders>()
                   .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.OrderId)
                   .IsIn(Ids);
```

If the list is empty I would like to return the whole Orders table. Is this possible to do this using NHiberbate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
var query = Session.QueryOver<Orders>();

if (ids == null || ids.Count == 0)
{
    query = query.WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.OrderId).IsIn(Ids);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Sure I can do that using two queries. I was just wondering if there is an NHibernate construct that I could use and don't have to write two queries...

Comment: This isn't two queries, that is it `DOES NOT` hit the DB twice. Its adding a optional where clause to an existing query. +1 from me